# Maximum Score of Each User with date filter

Tags: php

for instance i have following table structure

```
 userid  |  score  |      datestamp      |
-----------------------------------------------------
   1     |   44    |  2013-06-01 14:25:55 
   1     |   50    |  2013-06-02 14:25:55 
   2     |   59    |  2011-06-04 09:25:51 
   1     |   60    |  2011-06-10 21:25:15 
   3     |   19    |  2011-06-02 07:25:18
   2     |   70    |  2011-06-05 09:25:51 
   2     |   12    |  2011-06-08 09:25:51 
   3     |   60    |  2011-06-05 07:25:18
   4     |   30    |  2011-06-10 07:25:18
   3     |   20    |  2011-06-08 07:25:18
   4     |   15    |  2011-06-09 07:25:18
   1     |   50    |  2013-06-11 14:25:55 
   2     |   100   |  2013-06-15 14:25:55 
   3     |   160   |  2013-06-12 14:25:55 
   4     |   75    |  2013-06-16 14:25:55
```

I need such a query in which i will give date limits and it will give me maximum score of each user during that period. 
for example if i give start date 2013-06-01 and end date 2011-06-10, it will result in :

```
 userid  |  score  |      datestamp      |
----------------------------------------------------- 

  1     |   60    |  2011-06-10 21:25:15 

  2     |   70    |  2011-06-05 09:25:51 

  3     |   60    |  2011-06-05 07:25:18

  4     |   30    |  2011-06-10 07:25:18
```

Moreover it would be great if i give user Id also (using IN(1,2,3,4))

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the corresponding date along with it, and just the max score, this will work

```
SELECT
    userid, MAX(score)
FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    datestamp BETWEEN '2011-06-10 00:00:00' AND '2013-06-01 23:59:59'
    -- AND userid IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY
    userid
```

Getting the date associated with that will be more complicated, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query,

```
SELECT userid, MAX(score) as score FROM table 
WHERE datestamp BETWEEN '2011-06-10 00:00:00' AND '2013-06-01 23:59:59' AND userid IN(1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY userid
```